# How to get rid of the multiple top bars in gnome classic

Tags: 11.10, gnome-panel

Since upgrating to Ubuntu 11.10 I've been trying to get back to the look and feel of Gnome2. The closest I came is Gnome Classic, but I'm getting multiple (8) top bars.

[image]

Normally I would right click and delete these bars, but now it's not possible to right click on them. Any idea?

THanks!

Comment: not sure about 8 top-bars - never seen that, but to change and remove stuff requires a different key combination as described in this question and answer http://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What fossfreedom is referring to is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>right-click</kbd> on panel, and it works! Thanks.